# Returning a Pojo with some variable and ArrayList<otherPojo> from rest web service - how avoid LinkedHasрMap conversion

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jackson

My question is complete related to understand better the techniques to work with Json and check if I can do the way I was thinking as better practice. I am returning an `ArrayList<myPojo>` insinde the response from the rest web service and I can't understand why it always return it as `LinkedHashMap` even though I typed `ArrayList<myPojo>` in the model object I am using. Is there a way to return a `ArrayList<myPojo>` from rest web service or I really have to convert from `LinkedHasMap` to the expected object?

For instance, is there a way, maybe by using @Entity or some other annotation, to avoid the conversion below? The closest question I found in this fórum to my question is [ClassCastException: RestTemplate returning List<LinkedHashMap> instead of List<MymodelClass>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463372/classcastexception-resttemplate-returning-listlinkedhashmap-instead-of-listm) but it didn't answer the question if I can avoid the converter in client side and return an `ArrayList<myPojO>` - one reason because he is not declaring the webservice as I am and in this case `@GenericArguments(RedemptionDetail.class)`, `RedemptionDetail` is the exactly response and in my case the `ArrayList` is part of a more complex object (`LogDisplay`). I pasted the rest webservice relevant points below.

```
//the jars list

"aopalliance-1.0.jar"
"commons-logging-1.1.1.jar"
 "hibernate-validator-4.1.0.Final.jar"
"hibernate-validator-annotation-processor-4.1.0.Final.jar"
"jackson-annotations-2.2.3.jar"
"jackson-core-2.2.3.jar"
"jackson-databind-2.2.3.jar"
"slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar"
"slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar"
"spring-aop-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar"
"spring-beans-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar"
"spring-context-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar"
"spring-context-support-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar"
"spring-core-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar"
"spring-expression-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar"
"spring-web-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar"
"spring-webmvc-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar"
"validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar"

//rest web service
    @Controller
    public class Lo_Controller {
           @RequestMapping(value="myUrl", method=RequestMethod.POST)
           @ResponseBody

//client call
    LogDisplay _l = restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:8080/myApp/myRestService",myObjWithPasrameters, LogDisplay.class);

    //it will print class java.util.ArrayList
    System.out.printLn((lo_Values.setDisplayValues((_l.getDisplayValues()).getClass());

    //it will print class java.util.LinkedHashMap but I was expecting to get Lo_DisplayRecord type               
    System.out.printLn((lo_Values.setDisplayValues(_l.getDisplayValues().get(0))).getClass());

    /* when trying to cast (Lo_DisplayRecord)displayValues.get(0)
    I got the error
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap
     cannot be cast to com.my_app. Lo_DisplayRecord
    so I fixed it by using jackson.map.ObjectMapper as suggested in
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15430715/casting-linkedhashmap-to-complex-object
    */

    //Solution 1:
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Lo_DisplayRecord pojo = mapper.convertValue(displayValues.get(0), Lo_DisplayRecord.class);

    //Solution 2:
    byte[] json = mapper.writeValueAsBytes(displayValues.get(0));
    Lo_DisplayRecord pojo2 = mapper.readValue(json, Lo_DisplayRecord.class);

//the pojo     
    public class LogDisplay {
    private ArrayList<Lo_DisplayRecord> displayValues;
    //... others variables not relevants to the question
    public ArrayList<Lo_DisplayRecord> getDisplayValues() {
      return displayValues;
    }
```

Comment: I am looking forward to hear some suggestion about this thread. If someone needs extra details please let me know. A beggining point could be comment some way to deal with LinkedHashMap automatic conversion by Jackson and avoid converting it in client. I have searched in Internet about @GenericArguments and I didn't find any tutorial explaining it and, additionaly, looking at the only thread I readed it, it seems that this annotation is related to Jersey and I am using Spring as an already tooken decision .

Comment: I found other thread telling to update to Spring 4 as solution but I am still getting the same issue with LinkedHasMap type instead of the expected pojo after updated with Spring 4. Note: I am using JDK6. Below the thread 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24318910/java-lang-classcastexception-java-util-linkedhashmap-cannot-be-cast